# Regular expression (regex lookarounds) to detected a certain string not between certain strings (lookahead & lookbehind, word not surrounded by words)

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I trying to detect all occurrences of a certain string, that is not surrounded by certain strings (using regex lookarounds). Eg. all occurrences of "African" but not "South African Society". See a simplified example below.

```
#My example text:
text <- c("South African Society", "South African", 
"African Society", "South African Society and African Society")

#My code examples:
str_detect(text, "(?<!South )African(?! Society)")
#or
grepl("(?<!South )African(?! Society)",  perl=TRUE , text)

#I need:
[1] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE 

#instead of:
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The problem seems to be that regex evaluates the lookbehind and the lookahead separately and not as a whole. It should require both conditions and not only one.

Comment: You may use: `^(?!South African Society$).*\bAfrican\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(?<!South )African(?! Society)` pattern matches `African` when it is not preceded with neither `South`  nor  `Society`. If there is `South` or `Society` there will be no match.

There are several solutions.

```
 African(?<!South African(?= Society))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4R7oF/1). Here, `African` is only matched when the regex engine does not find `South African` at the position after matching `African` substring that is immediately followed with space and `Society`. Using this check after `African` is more efficient in case there are longer strings that do not match the pattern than moving it before the word `African` (see [the `(?<!South (?=African Society))African` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4R7oF/3)).

Alternatively, you may use a [SKIP-FAIL technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
South African Society(*SKIP)(*F)|African
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4R7oF/2). Here, `South African Society` is matched first, and `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes this match fail and proceed to the next match, so `African` is matched in all contexts other than `South African Society`.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, you re the one! Thx a lot. Just a tiny add-on to my simplified question. In practice, I need to exclude a lot of organizations' names from my matches (eg. "African Journal", "Royal African Society" etc.). What would you consider the most efficient coding for that?

Comment: @MrGISRocker Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @MrGISRocker `(*SKIP)(*F)` technique will be the simplest if you want to avoid manual pattern building.